Visual Studio Installer Project / VDPROJ: No option to delete blue-underlined files in File System
Today with no changes, Installers built from our Visual Studio Installer Project are failing to install with:
The file '00DD254FD6A48F3F50858FBE393851B0' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file `_EF0346E517198CC1799F225FDE20F75E'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Inspecting the File System of the project shows many files with blue underlines: 
I don't see the actual error described and the option to delete the file is grayed out. The file does exist. Readding simply adds a second file to the list without removing the first.
We faced a similar issue in the past with red-underlined files which was resolved with a clean reinstall of visual studio, but this time that has no effect.
I've tried to go through the VDPROJ file and manually all references to these files. "System.Threading.Thread.dll" does not exist in the VDPROJ, yet the project clings on to it, seemingly somewhere secret.
How can the files be deleted or more information be obtained to troubleshoot this? We're currently facing having to recreate our Installer Project from scratch, but this will be unbelievably time consuming to do.
